# Printing all pairs of combinations from a given set of numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand why it is that the combinations of -let's say- 0 and 1 are only: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)] and why (1,0) is not included.

The same goes for all the **combinations of pairs** of 0,1,2,3.
**I would like to get:** (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)

But my code is only giving me: `[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]`

My/the code, which I got from realpython.com/python-itertools/ :

```
import itertools as com

x = list(com.combinations_with_replacement([0,1,2,3], 2))
```

How can I edit the code so that it prints all the desired combinations?

Comment: Go back to the `itertools` docs and read about the `product` method.

Comment: Sidenote: I would suggest reading the documentation from the official Python website. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 3):

You would want to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) since you want the cartesian product:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product([0, 1, 2, 3], repeat=2))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Note you don't want to use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) since the output will not contain entries like `(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), or (3, 3)` since each element in the iterable is only used once.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get all possible combinations, you need to use the [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function:

```
import itertools as com

x = list(com.product([0,1,2,3], repeat=2))
print(x)
```

As stated in Python docs, this is the same as:

```
x = [(y,z) for y in [0,1,2,3] for z in [0,1,2,3]]
```

This will return:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```